# Automating gdb - Piping stdin and stdout for gdb

Tags: java, automation, gdb

I have a requirement of tracking changes to some set of variables in a given application from start to end of program. I thought of using gdb.

How planned it at high level is, start gdb, set watch-points to all my variables (they are all global for now), and execute "run" command, and once there is any change, gdb would log that and stop at that location and I would execute "continue". Do this continuously till application exits. Hence I should be having detailed logs to all the required variables.

To automate this process, I wrote a java code where I open gdb as sub-process and try to interact with it using handle to sub-process's stdin and stdout. 
I am creating sub-process in Java using processbuilder class, and writing to stdin and stdout of the sub-process created. But it doesn't seem to be working the way I thought it would work. Basically from reading stdout, I can see that gdb is starting and loading required target application, but for some reason I am unable to interact with GDB by writing to its stdin.

Here is my test code I wrote to automate gdb

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GDBTest {
    private InputStream outStr = null;
    private OutputStream inpStr = null;
    private boolean state = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GDBTest gdb = new GDBTest();
        gdb.test(null);
    }

    public void test(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add("gdb");
        cmd.add("testApp");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        try { 
            Process p = pb.start();
            inpStr = p.getOutputStream();   /* Handle to the stdin of process */
            outStr = p.getInputStream();    /* Handle to the stdout of process */
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outStr));

            while(true) {
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                state = br.ready();
                if(state == false) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            inpStr.write("watch c88\n".getBytes());
            while(br.ready()) {
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }

            inpStr.write("run\n".getBytes());
            while(br.ready()) {
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure whats wrong with this! Can someone please suggest how to automate GDB this way.

Thanks,

Microkernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh figured it out, I was missing inpStr.flush()... It fixed everything!